# Fetch only needed data from CoreDate or everything?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, swift3

my question may sound a bit confusing, but I couldn't find a better title. Let me explain: I'm developing an iOS App which uses CoreData to store objects and make them persistent. I want to display the stored objects in an `UITableView`. Every object contains a *date*. I want my table view to show the objects sorted by date, and every month is a section inside that table view.

```
+--------------------+
+---  March 2016  ---+
+--------------------+
+ - Entry 1          +
+ - Entry 2          +
+--------------------+
+-- February 2016  --+
+--------------------+
+ - Entry 1          +
+ .....              +
.
.
.
.
+--------------------+
```

Since the table view needs to know how many rows and sections there are **before** the data is displayed, I need to know at least how many entries there are inside my CoreData storage.

**Approach 1**

I fetch only the dates of each object and tell the table view how many rows it has to display. When the data source method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` gets called, I fetch the data for exactly the objects I need. Is CoreData fast enough to do that, or does the user have to wait a moment until the data is loaded?

**Approach 2**

I fetch everything from my CoreData storage and "store" the objects in my `ViewController` which holds the table view. Maybe it needs a lot of memory to keep every single object in memory.

**Approach 3** (*lazy loading* ?)

I fetch the latest 10-20 objects from CoreData. When the user scrolls down the table view and is about to reach the last entry, I fetch the next 10-20 entries and display them. What about the entries I loaded at first? Should I keep them in memory? Or fetch them again if the user scrolls up to the top?

I don't want to "waste" time on that and try every single one of them myself, I hope you can help me and someone has experience with that kind of stuff. Thank you!

Comment: Approach 3 is best for you. Once the objects are fetched store them in a variable array in your view controller. When the user fetches more, append your array and reload your table.

Remember that you can also fetch counts only if that's all you need, but that may not be the best strategy here.

Comment: Have you looked at `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [NSFetchedRequestController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/) to fetch data and, if needed, add NSPredicate's to it. Enjoy:-)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NSFetchedResultsControler`.  None of the options you listed appear correct because this requirement is already supported by the framework.  You should not worry about the what to fetch at all.  Just provide the correct configuration and everything will be taken care of by the framework.

When you instantiate `NSFetchedResultsController`, supply the `sectionNameKeyPath` parameter.  Your fetch result will be grouped based on this attribute.  It can be a calculated attribute as in your cases, the month and year of your record.